# Recurring weekly NGINX 502 issue

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

Every Monday morning my (Digital Ocean) server goes down and produces a 502 gateway error. It's not always at exactly the same time, give or take a few hours. I'm unable to diagnose the issue, but here's what I've tried:

- Ensured that the box is secure
- Checked that there are no running cron jobs
- Verified that no suspicious services are running
- Scoured over the log files to see if there's any suspicious behavior
- Auditing the application to check for memory leaks or other causes (none)
- Checked that sufficient memory and disk space is available

The only possibly useful information I could find is the following:

```
[ 2016-11-21 02:35:02.0177 1064/7fde41b9e7c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:891 ]: Watchdog seems to be killed; forcing shutdown of all subprocesses

[ 2016-11-21 02:35:02.0180 1064/7fde3b3ce700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:532 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [info] 18431#18431: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/11/21 02:35:02 [emerg] 18432#18432: still could not bind()
2016/11/21 07:08:09 [info] 941#941: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76
[ 2016-11-21 07:08:09.3136 1064/7f40eccd47c0 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2016-11-21 07:08:09.3249 1113/7fb32c9647c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2016-11-21 07:08:09.3250 1113/7fb32c9647c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2016-11-21 07:08:09.3282 1113/7fb32c9647c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 1113
[ 2016-11-21 07:08:09.3586 1125/7fa68d1a57c0 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2016-11-21 07:08:09.3689 1125/7fa68d1a57c0 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 1125
```

Software versions being used:

1. Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
2. nginx/1.10.1
3. Phusion Passenger 5.0.30
4. Ruby 2.3.0

The server would be running fine in the time leading up to this. Any direction on solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found anything relevant in Passeger logs?

Comment: Is your passenger configured to restart worker after a certain time or a certain number of handled requests?

Comment: @spickermann Nothing what so ever.

Comment: @alejdg I've been monitoring the logs closely and the only suspicious lines are the ones pasted above.